Validation Error When Deploying Inbound Change Set
Currently attempting to deploy an inbound change set containing 2 Apex Triggers & Test classes which:

prevent a merge from occurring on a contact with cases associated with it
prevent the change of an email field on a contact with cases associated with it
I tested both triggers & test classes in our sandbox instance and everything ran successfully. When attempting to validate the inbound change set which I sent from sandbox to our prod environment using the "Run Local Tests" option, I receive the following error messages:


PreventContactMergeAndDeleteTest  testPreventMergeContactWithCase System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected an exception when merging contacts.
Stack Trace:  Class.PreventContactMergeAndDeleteTest.testPreventMergeContactWithCase: line 30, column 1


PreventContactMergeAndDeleteTest  testPreventMergeIntoContactWithCase System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected an exception when merging into a contact with cases.
Stack Trace:  Class.PreventContactMergeAndDeleteTest.testPreventMergeIntoContactWithCase: line 67, column 1


PreventEmailChangeIfCasesExistTest    testPreventEmailChange  System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Unexpected error message: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 003OJ00000QcL37YAF; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, PreventContactMergeAndDelete: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors Trigger.PreventContactMergeAndDelete: line 9, column 1: []
Stack Trace: Class.PreventEmailChangeIfCasesExistTest.testPreventEmailChange: line 26, column 1

How can I resolve such that I can successfully validate & deploy both apex triggers & test classes to our live production instance?

Are your tests failing in your sandbox? If they aren't, then have you used any hard-coded Ids in your tests? If so, then you'll need to change that (probably by creating test data inside of the test class itself) since the records in your sandbox will not exist in production and/or their Ids will be different (unless it's a partial copy/full copy sandbox and the records were copied from production).

read up on test isolation principles -- unit tests should avoid relying on org data

@DerekF, the triggers and test classes are doing what they are supposed to in the sandbox environment however when I attempt to implement in prod via change sets (as my org does not allow me to write apex triggers & classes directly in the test environment) and validate them, I am met with the errors above

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You need to [edit] your post to include important details about your unit tests, especially how you've set up your test data, and also include the relevant portions of your Apex methods that are failing.
